# Почему при выполнении одной проверки тест пройден, а другой выдаёт ошибку org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <true> but was: <false>

Tags: java, junit, test-automation, rest-assured

[image: Скрин 2] 1. Когда я перебираю список avatars с ids - тест считается пройденным.
2. Но если перебираю другие списки - выдаёт ошибку

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <true> but was: <false>
```

**Код**

```
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.internal.common.assertion.Assertion;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.when;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;


public class ReqresTest {
    private final static String URL = "https://reqres.in/";

    @Test
    public void checkAvatarAndIdTest(){
        List<UserData>users = given()
                .when()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .get(URL + "api/users?page=2")
                .then().log().all()
                .extract().body().jsonPath().getList("data", UserData.class);

      //  users.forEach(x-> Assertions.assertTrue(x.getAvatar().contains(x.getId().toString())));
       // Assertions.assertTrue(users.stream().allMatch(x->x.getEmail().endsWith("reqres.in")));

        List<String> avatars = users.stream().map(UserData::getAvatar).toList();
        List<String> ids = users.stream().map(x -> x.getId().toString()).toList();
        List<String> emails = users.stream().map(UserData::getEmail).toList();
        List<String> fns = users.stream().map(UserData::getFirst_name).toList();

       /* for(int i = 0; i < avatars.size(); i++){
            Assertions.assertTrue(avatars.get(i).contains(ids.get(i)));
        }*/

        for(int i = 0; i < fns.size(); i++){
            Assertions.assertTrue(fns.get(i).contains(ids.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Подробная ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрим для примера `fns`. В этот список вы поместили имена пользователей этим кодом:

```
List<String> fns = users.stream().map(UserData::getFirst_name).toList();
```

А проверка `fns.get(i).contains(ids.get(i))` проверяет, что в имени пользователя с индексом `i` (т.е. в `fns.get(i)`) содержится его идентификатор (`ids.get(i)`) как подстрока (`contains` тут - это метод у класса `String`). Не знаю, что именно хранится в идентификаторах пользователей, но скорее всего не first name пользователя.

Не ясно что собой представляет поле аватар, но очевидно, в строке, которую возвращает `getAvatar` содержится идентификатор пользователя, как подстрока.

Comment: Не уверен, что я полностью правильно вас понял, но:
1. В идентификаторе fns.get(i) - имена (Jonh, Peter и тд)
1. В идентификаторе ids.get(i) - ID пользователя (1, 2, 3 и тд)
1. Суть проверки в том, что бы проверить, что в массиве данных пользователей есть как ID, так и first_name.
1. Если будет понятнее, что имею ввиду, то я пользуюсь сайтом https://reqres.in/ метод GET List User
1. Так же, добавил 2-й скрин, что написано в Классе UserData

Comment: Ну вот для примера возвращает ` fns.get(i)` строку `Jonh`, а `ids.get(i)` строку `1`. И `contains` проверяет, что **строка** `1`  содержится в **строке** `John`.

Comment: Кажется я понял, возможно повторю ваши слова, но смысл таков: Строка 1 проверяет, содержится ли в строке Jonh. И, что довольно очевидно, в Jonh мы не видим цифры 1 и поэтому выдаёт ошибку. Тогда, как я могу проверить каждый fns.get? Ведь имена в них разные

Comment: Какая цель этого теста? Зачем он нужен?

Comment: Цель - обучение, что бы понять как правильно писать код для GET запросов ну и в целом понять логику написания кода

Comment: Обучение - это мета-цель. Чтоб ответить на вопрос "как проверить в тесте то-то" нужно понимать зачем этот тест существует. Что он проверяет и зачем.